# Combine two strategy with different pyramiding

Tags: pine-script

I want to combine the two strategies, first strategy) I will buy in one step and I will sell in one step, second strategy) I will buy in 3 steps *when the price cross down MA 7, MA 14, and MA 20, and I will sell in one step. How I should combine these two strategies? Because first one uses pyramiding 1 and second one uses pyramiding 3.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the two scrips do not need to interact. Try running them separately.